# Solr auto suggest (suggester) returns no results

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I am quite new to `using` solr5.1 - and I am now playing around to see if I can get the autosuggest to work. So, the background is that I have a core named `docs` and I post documents to this collection using something along the lines of:

```
/bin/post -c docs /path/to/my/docs/*.pdf
```

..and I have the documents indexed. Now, I tweak the `solrconfig.xml`, located within my core directory to include autosuggest. So, borrowing some code from [here](http://lucidworks.com/blog/solr-suggester/), I include the following:

```xml
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>

    <!-- Substitute these for the two above for another "flavor"
    <str name=”lookupImpl”>AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name=”indexPath”>suggester_infix_dir</str>
    -->

    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">_text_</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Now, I do:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/docs/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=mode
```

and I always seem to get:

```json
{"responseHeader":
  {"status":0,"QTime":19},
  "command":"build","suggest":
   {"mySuggester":   
     {"mode":
       {"numFound":0,"suggestions":[]}
     }
   }
 }
```

I am not entirely sure what is it that I am doing wrong - I was wondering if I should be modifying the `solrconfig.xml` before adding any docs? or was it something wrong with the snippet of code inserted into it? Also, I am not sure if this line:

```
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
```

is correct. I read that use of `string` should not be used - but again, I see the solr docs using it.

I have also tried code from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester), but it seems to give me the same results - i.e no suggested words.

Any help on this would be great.

*UPDATE: #01:*

I have recently been reading that some features of solr need `stored=true` to work. I am now wondering if this applies to `Suggester`. So, do I need to turn the `text` field in `solr.xml` to `stored=true`?

Comment: could you share the schema.xml?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti: the schema.xml is simply the default one - I have not modified this. Does that help? I have also added an update to the question.

Comment: whats the fieldType used for the field <str name="field">_text_</str> where you are looking for autosuggest?

Comment: <fields>
        <field name="_text_" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" />
</fields> . There is no need of stored = true but indexed = true is must.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti: I do not excatly know what fieldtype is being used for `text` - is this in `schema.xml`? On the solr admin panel, I go to `SchemaBrowser` and it shows me fields - of which `_text_` is one - and I presumed this is where solr is storing the indexed documents. Is this wrong?

Comment: on my `schema.xml` I have `<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>` So, I have changed `<str name="field">_text_</str>` to `<str name="field">text</str>` and `<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>` to `<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>`. I then restart the server and issue: `http://localhost:8983/solr/docs/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=mode+l` but, I still get 0 results :(